# How to include/extend/re-use forms in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have 2 forms. The frist half of the form is the same for my both forms. The second half is different.
I would like to only write the first half of the form once, then including it or extending it with the second half of the form.

My classes

```
class Hero {
  hp: number;
}

class Warrior extends Hero {
  attack: number;
}

class Mage extends Hero {
  mana: number;
}
```

My components and templates

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-warrior',
  templateUrl: "<form (ngSubmit)=\"save()\">\n" +
               "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.hp\">\n" +
               "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.attack\">\n" +
               "</form>\n",
})
export class EditWarrior {
  hero: Warrior;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-mage',
  templateUrl: "<form (ngSubmit)=\"save()\">\n" +
               "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.hp\">\n" +
               "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.mana\">\n" +
               "</form>\n",
})
export class EditMage {
  hero: Mage;
}
```

I would like to have a component/file that contains the generic part of my form, and be able to include it. For exemple, let's imagine:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-hero',
  templateUrl: "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.hp\">\n"
})
export class EditHero {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
}
```

To have something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-warrior',
  templateUrl: "<form (ngSubmit)=\"save()\">\n" +
                "    <hero-edit [hero]="hero"></hero-edit>\n" +
                "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.attack\">\n" +
                "</form>\n",
})
export class EditWarrior {
  hero: Warrior;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-mage',
  templateUrl: "<form (ngSubmit)=\"save()\">\n" +
                "    <hero-edit [hero]="hero"></hero-edit>\n" +
                "    <input class=\"form-control\" [(ngModel)]=\"hero.mana\">\n" +
                "</form>\n",
})
export class EditMage {
  hero: Mage;
}
```

Is it possible in Angular 2 ?
I may try to use another architecture ?
Any help, documentation, idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why not, seems reasonable to reuse components. Have you tried it? Any issue you encountered?

Comment: When I modify my hero inside EditHro, the modifications aren't reported in my EditWarrior.